# I want a case statetement that count more than 1 as 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help solve the below query.

The column in question has Y and N and I want the N to show zero and the Y to show 1.

I want it to **aggregate the no of times** visited for each machine and `if >= 1 to show 1`. Client requirement is whether machine has been visited regardless of the number of times.

```
   Select MachineNo,
         [Date_of_Visit],
        Month([Date_of_Visit])[Month],
        Year([Date_of_Visit])[Year],
        sum(case when [Visited] = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end)[No of Visits]             
FROM [MachineVisit]
Group by [Date_of_Visit],
         [MachineNo]
```

Comment: Just wrap the sum in another `case`. Or use `max` instead of `sum`. Or even better, handle this kind of stuff in your application rather than the query :)

Comment: @Luaan sometimes there is no "app" to handle this...

Comment: Let us see the whole query . there may be a more efficient way to do this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Max` instead of `Sum`

```
Max(case when [Visited] = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end)[Visits]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little confusing, the way it is written, but I am assuming you want something like:

```
select sum(case when [visited] >1 then 1 else null end) visists
from visit_table
where visit_date = '2015-01-30'
```

This is assuming that you have a table that counts the visits for a single day for 1 IP address as single entry.

If you have a table that has an entry for every single page visit, then you would probably need to do:

```
select count(distinct ip_address)
from (
     select ip_address
     from visit_table
     where visit_date = '2015-01-30'
     group by ip_address
     having count(1) >1
     ) x
```

**EDIT:**

Well then the simplist way should be:

```
select count(1)
from visit_table
where [visited]='Y'
     and visit_date = '2015-01-30'
;
```

That should work...

Although  I don't have the table in front of me - so if this doesn't work, please post the fully query.

Comment: thanks walker, the column contains Y and N only but all clients care about is the fact the machine has been visited. It doesnt matter the no of times in the day as statement is grouped daily. so results should display 1 for any machine visited >=1 daily.